# Output array won't take the value of an array register

Tags: verilog, active-hdl

In a simple module I have defined a 4-bit array register, and I use it to assign a value to a 4-bit array output. The output acts like a 1-bit wire even if it has been defined as a 4-bit array.

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module test(input in,
            output wire [3:0] outpt);

    reg [3:0] A = 4;    
    assign outpt = A;

endmodule

module testbench1();

    test tst(in, outpt);
    initial begin
        $strobe("| %d | %d |",outpt,tst.A);
    end

endmodule
```

When I run the testbench: If A = 5, then output will be 1. If A = 4 the output will be 0. Output acts like 1-bit even though I have defined it as 4-bit array.

I'm using .v files and the program Active HDL 10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly declared `outpt` as 4-bit in `test`.  Since you did not explicitly declare `outpt` in `testbench1`, it defaults to 1-bit.  You should declare it as:

`wire [3:0] outpt;`

Some simulators will generate a warning message about this.  Try your code on edaplayground.